# I have a website that can only be accessed via https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, apache, certbot

I have a apache/RoR server running on 8080 port and redbird forwarding from port 80 (because I have a nodejs website running on the same machine). The problem is that when I try to connect my RoR website from http, it gives me 500 error or the GET fails. Below is my apache setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        DocumentRoot /home/ffit/gsatech/production/current/public
        ServerName cobranca.gsatech.com.br
        ServerAlias www.cobranca.gsatech.com.br

        RailsEnv production

        <Directory "/home/ffit/gsatech/production/current/public">
                #Options -MultiViews
                #Allow from all
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-gsatech-production.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-gsatech-production.log combined
        PassengerRuby /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby

        LoadModule passenger_module /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.1.8/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
        <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerRoot /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.1.8
        PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby
        </IfModule>

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cobranca.gsatech.com.br
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cobranca.gsatech.com.br [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.cobranca.gsatech.com.br
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my app.js for my redbird forwarding to apache.

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80, xfwd: false});

proxy.register("dicoop.ffit.com.br", "http://dicoop.ffit.com.br:3030");

proxy.register("http://cobranca.gsatech.com.br", "https://cobranca.gsatech.com.br:8080");

proxy.register("www.cobranca.gsatech.com.br", "https://cobranca.gsatech.com.br:8080");
```

Apache is running port 81 while my Redbird module is running on port 80 to do the routing through my websites and I have certbot doing my https certificate for my RoR website.

Comment: I think ports are conflict with each other.

Comment: How so? Redbird is on port 80, apache is on 81, my RoR website is on 8080 and my nodejs website is on 3030. Did I missed something?

Comment: Post you error please !

Comment: Here:
cobranca.gsatech.com.br/:1 GET http://cobranca.gsatech.com.br/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
Navigated to http://cobranca.gsatech.com.br/